# Resizing linked excel content in a word document

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365, merge

I am using Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus and created a word document and excel document.  I need to include various sections of the excel document in the word document (see examples of the word, excel, and merged document below).

I also need to keep the excel sections in the word document as objects so that when excel is updated, the merged word document is updated.

I found that I can paste the excel document as a link which partially meets my needs.  But, after doing so, the excel section is much too large, and extends past the word boarder.  How can I shrink the excel section so that it fits within the word document?  Note that while it would be nice, it is not necessary to use word's autofit (this option goes away when pasted as a link).

Also, not critical, but if it is possible to include a header row above each of the excel sections, please advise.  Otherwise, I can just add the header to each of the sections in the excel document.

PS.  If this cannot be done just using word and excel, but can be accomplished with some 3rd party software, doing so might be an option.

Thanks

[image]

**Word Document:**

[image]

**Excel Document:**

[image]

**Merged Document:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer removed - Not much point posting to a site - even if it is a Q&A site - when the OPs cannot be bothered to respond.

Comment: Thanks yokki and sorry for my absence.  So, one uses the image to define that size first?  Interesting.